# How to characterize a subfield of $\mathbb C$ that is closed under taking absolute values?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

Is there a necessary or sufficient condition for a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb C$ to be closed under taking absolute values? Certainly not all subfields have this property, since $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q(1+i)$.

Comment: It may be easier (but different) to start with fields that are closed under taking *square* absolute values.